# How do I modify JSX inside a React useState

Tags: reactjs

I have a React state which contains the JSX component as a value. I want to modify that.

```
const [el, setEl] = useState([
  {
    id: "1",
    data: {
      label: (
        <>
          <CardHeader>Card 1</CardHeader>
        </>
      )
    }
  },  
  {
    id: "2",
    data: {
      label: (
        <>
          <CardHeader>Card 2</CardHeader>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
])

return (
      <ReactFlow
       elements={el}
       onConnect={onConnect}
       onElementsRemove={onElementsRemove}
       onLoad={onLoad}
      />
)
```

I tried this approach but somehow it didn't work

```
const [el, setEl] = useState([
  {
    id: "1",
    data: {
      title: "Test"
      label: () => {
      return (
        <>
          <CardHeader>{this.title}</CardHeader>
        </>
      )}
    }
  },  {
    id: "2",
    data: {
      title: "ID 2"
      label: () => {
      return (
        <>
          <CardHeader>{this.title}</CardHeader>
        </>
      )}
    }
  }]
)
```

#### Expected:

If I update the `title` then the JSX should also change, or if there is a way that can modify JSX itself then also it will work.

If anyone can give some better approach to fix this problem, would really be helpful.

***Thanks***

Comment: That looks very weird. If at all possible, I'd remove the `label` function entirely, and change the *consumer* to lookup the item's `title`

Comment: I know but the library `Reactflow` expects the `label` object to be in JSX

Comment: Can you show where you're using the `el` state elsewhere in an edit to the question? Eg is it returned while rendering or something?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? What do you expect to happen? And what happened instead?

Comment: nope it didnt work @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated the first codeblock

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use `this.title` within that function and have it refer to the title of the `data` object, you need a regular function keyword function, not an arrow function. Arrow functions don't have their own context, so they won't be able to refer to the proper object. Arrow function context is set at definition time not at call time–in this case you need the context to be set at call time, so you need a regular function.

```js
const [el, setEl] = useState([
  {
    id: "1",
    data: {
      title: "Test"
      label: (function() {
      return (
        <>
          <CardHeader>{this.title}</CardHeader>
        </>
      )})()
    }
  },  {
    id: "2",
    data: {
      title: "ID 2"
      label: (function() {
      return (
        <>
          <CardHeader>{this.title}</CardHeader>
        </>
      )})()
    }
  }]
)
```

### Edited

Looking more at the documentation, it looks like you can use `{}` within the component that you return the same way you would in a normal component. You'd just need to make sure that you have a variable with the information you'd want to add to the label. This is an example from the source code

```js
const label1 = "Test"
const label2 = "ID 2"
const [el, setEl] = useState([
  {
    id: "1",
    data: {
      title: "Test"
      label: (function() {
      return (
        <>
          <CardHeader>{label1}</CardHeader>
        </>
      )})()
    }
  },  {
    id: "2",
    data: {
      title: "ID 2"
      label: (function() {
      return (
        <>
          <CardHeader>{label2}</CardHeader>
        </>
      )})()
    }
  }]
)
```

as long as you only are adding one node at a time this should work, no?

Comment: I tried that way as well but in return, I  get () fn not React component in console.log

Comment: ah, I think you need to call the function so you have the JSX, let me edit my answer

Comment: btw, it's the library that consumes this Array and builds nodes out of it.

Comment: I am getting this `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: yeah... the issue is the `this` value, :thinking_face:

Comment: I'm looking through the docs now trying to see if they have any examples with dynamic content in them. Only thing I can think of is if there's some was to call that function using `.call()` to specify a particular object, but I'm not sure how you'd get a reference to the particular data object you'd want to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229631/discussion-between-dakota-lee-martinez-and-xenon).